# can't send messages to created bot?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

Okay, so, I'm trying to create a QnA bot with Azure and Microsoft Bot Framework. I think I managed to create it and got it linked to Teams, but when I go to Teams to test it, it gives me this message in the chat box:

"Sending new messages to this bot has been disabled by your administrator."

I'm not sure what I did wrong or how to fix it. I'm also not sure how I can link a bot I made with QnA Maker into the bot I just created with Azure. The tutorials I found online all talk about using Bot Service (preview) in Azure, but I can't choose that one from the available list.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have just faced to the same issue

Comment: Did Doga's link help solve your problem? Are you receiving any additional error messages?

Answer (score 3):

Your Tenant Admin needs to go to the Teams Admin Centre:

- Open the Teams Apps pulldown
- Select Permission Policies
- Click the "Org-wide app setttings" button in the top RH corner.

> This shortcut will get them there: [admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/app-permission](https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/policies/app-permission)

- From Org-wide app settings turn on one (or both?) of "Allow third party or custom apps", or just "Custom apps" (I'm not sure which it is these days) and then click Save.

Be aware that replication delays could take some hours or even overnight before this change manifests to you as a user though.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your Office 365 admin has not enabled side-loading of Apps in MS-Teams for your user.

Ask the Admin to allow Side-Loading of Apps for you in the Admin console on the O365 dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, it seems like the administrator needs to allow sideloading of apps.
see here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoftteams/teams-app-permission-policies

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The tutorial is old

In Azure Portal, When creating, try to go to

AI + Machine Learning > Web App Bot

And Select Q&A if you are using QnA.

Then in Application Settings, scroll down and you will find

QnAKnowledgebaseId(1)

QnAAuthKey(2)

QnAEndpointHostName(3)

You put all the information you get from QnA

```
POST /knowledgebases/(1)xxxxxxxx/generateAnswer

Host: (3)https://xxxxxx

Authorization: QnAEndpointKey (2)xxxxxx

Content-Type: application/json
{"question":"<Your question>"}
```